# How we can define the scope in java?

Tags: java, scope

How we can define the scope in java?
Ex:

```
public class ScopeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x=10;
        if(x==10){
            x=20;
            System.out.println("X:" +x);
            System.out.println("X:" +x);
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
X:20
X:20
```

I want:

```
X=20
X=10
```

Comment: You can't do what you want to do.

Comment: Consider naming your variables something different...?

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: this model program is wrong.you declared an variable x=10.you change that then the change will be the result.here nothing special with scope. if you redeclares inside the if{} na it will be meaningful some what.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one local variable in the current scope.

What you can do is have a variable as a member and a local variable.

```
class ScopeTest {
    static int x = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (x == 10) {
            int x = 20;
            System.out.println("X:" + x);
            System.out.println("X:" + ScopeTest.x);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you had an instance with inheritance as well, you could use `super.x`

```
class ScopeTest {
    int x = -10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClassTest().printX();
    }
}

class SubClassTest extends ScopeTest {
    static int x = 10;

    public void printX() {
        if (x == 10) {
            int x = 20;
            System.out.println("x:" + x);
            System.out.println("SubClassTest.x:" + SubClassTest.x);
            System.out.println("super.x:" + super.x);
        }

    }
}
```

prints

```
x:20
SubClassTest.x:10
super.x:-10
```